# A Missing Vowels Mishap

Tags: knowledge, english

How exciting! Your first day as a BBC intern, and you get to meet *the* Victoria Coren Mitchell! You take a deep breath as you walk up to her dressing room, not wanting to sound like a crazed, nervous maniac in front of her. All ready, you open the door slightly and poke your head in.

“Fifteen minutes till showt—uh...”

Well you certainly didn’t expect this. A bawling Victoria, huddled in a ball on the floor, next to a large puddle of wine. You slowly step inside.

“Is, um...is something wrong?” You roll your eyes. Duh, of course something is wrong, look at her!

Victoria gets up and sprints over to you. “You! You have to help me. I was having a quick drink before the show, and I accidentally knocked the wine bottle *all* over the cards for the Missing Vowels round! I don’t know what any of the connections or the answers are supposed to be! And now my makeup’s all screwed up and I don’t have time to get new cards...”

“So, uh,” you say, half confused and half starstruck, “what exactly do you want me to do?”

“Just figure out the answers for each of the clues, and what each group’s connection is! Write it on that napkin over there or something!” she says as she runs out of the room. “And, well, maybe clean up this mess while you’re at it...”

You turn your attention to the wine puddle, and see five cards in the middle of it. Picking them up, you take another deep breath. This is your time to shine! You haven’t watched Only Connect all these years for nothing!

**Can you solve all of the clues, and figure out the connection between each group of four?**

(In case you don't know how the Missing Vowels round works on Only Conncect, a word or phrase has all its vowels removed, and spaces are added randomly between the consonants. For example, `ONLY CONNECT` becomes `NL YCNN CT`.)

---

The wine-soaked cards:

[image: Card 1]

[image: Card 2]

[image: Card 3]

[image: Card 4]

[image: Card 5]

The cards as plaintext:

```
Group 1:
LVN
MNT SNH VN
P
HL LS FRM

Group 2:
CRN M
THR SS TNC
XSN DLLS
MH TP

Group 3:
NG LS
CRN
R SSS CH
RB

Group 4:
T HGSL VN DFTB LL
FRDC PL SND G LF
BT HJMHM MDN DFN CNG
YZ RHNY NDF G RSK TNG

Group 5:
TRS SC
SD RN
P LGN
QT RNRY
```

Comment: Is each card a single phrase or is each card made up of 4 separate words?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Each card has four different words/phrases.

Comment: Will it be obvious what the solution is? i.e. will there be something that indicates `P` is specifically `UP` or `APE`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Once you work out a few clues in a group, the connection should become clear enough that you'll be able to solve the ones you're unsure about. So in your example, once you get the other three in that first group, `P` should be rather obvious. Alternatively, you can start by guessing at what `P` could be (`UP`, `APE`, whatever), then think about some connections related to that clue that would connect to the others in the group.

Comment: I love your story.  It is great for this puzzle!

Comment: @Jason_ Haha, thank you very much! I needed a reason to have the answers covered up, and you can't go wrong with some wine :)

Comment: The crazy thing is, I totally read all of Victoria's lines in her voice.

Comment: OK, so now I've got three groups (and I believe GentlePurpleRain had them too but was trying to solve the whole thing before posting) and two others have got one each. I got more but they got much harder ones. Shall I communitiwikify my answer and add the other ones in, or what?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, a community wiki should be fine!

Comment: OK, done. (And Joe's and Peregrine's answers upvoted to compensate for their not getting the nice green checkmark.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have groups 2, 4, and 5. Groups 1 and 3 were found by Peregrine Rook and Joe Z., respectively, and I am including their answers here.

Group 1: They are all

> things that should be preceded by SEVEN:
>  ELEVEN
>  MINUTES IN HEAVEN
>  UP
>  HILLS OF ROME

Group 2: They are all

> board games:
>  CRANIUM
>  AXIS AND ALLIES
>  THE RESISTANCE
>  IMHOTEP

Group 3: They are all

> languages, named in other languages:
>  INGLESE
>  CORÉEN
>  RUSSISCH
>  ARABE

(At least one of these admits other related vowel-interpolations.)

Group 4: They are all

> eminent sports people and their sports:
>  THIAGO SILVA AND FOOTBALL
>  FRED COUPLES AND GOLF
>  IBTIHAJ MUHAMMAD AND FENCING
>  YUZURU HANYU AND FIGURE SKATING.

(It is possible that they have something more specific in common; I am very far from expert in this area.)

Group 5: They are all

> geological periods:
>  TRIASSIC
>  SIDERIAN
>  PALEOGENE
>  QUATERNARY

Comment: Those were the three I got, too.  :(

Comment: All correct so far! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44450/discussion-between-gareth-mccaughan-and-gentlepurplerain).

Answer (score 9):

Group 1:

> ELEVEN
> MINUTES IN HEAVEN
> UP
> HILLS OF ROME
>
> which are all things that can be preceded by SEVEN- or SEVEN.

Comment: Correct, well done!

Comment: Wow, I was right, it _was_ eleven. That one was interesting.

Answer (score 8):

Group 3 seems like it would be:

> ENGELS, CORÉEN, RUSSISCH, ÁRABE (names of languages in other languages)

Comment: That's correct, well done! :)

Comment: Good thing I took German this year to know the third one. Otherwise I never would have gotten it.

Comment: This seems a little arbitrary.  If other languages are fair game, you could make just about anything fit.  Is there any pattern to the languages, or is it just four random languages?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I intended to just have four random languages. You're right that this is kinda arbitrary, I forgot to check if other languages would have the same consonant pattern as others. I only realized after everyone was bringing up other possibilities (like `INGLESE` and `ENGELS` when I had intended `INGLÉS`) that I probably should've checked beforehand. My bad!